# spring - messageSource

Tags: spring-mvc

> org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'user.username.empty' for locale 'en_GB'.

Currently I have the following code:

`applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
      p:basename="messages" />
```

What I'm trying to do is cause an error to appear for the user if when they try and register on my site with a blank username, it will give them the error defined as `user.username.empty`. My application is working as intended and it's looking for the error `user.username.empty`, however it cannot find it no matter where I put the properties file.

What folder do I need to put the properties file and how do I need it named?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be named `messages.properties`, and be in the classpath, in the default package. And it must of course contain such a line:

```
user.username.empty=the message you want
```

You may customize it for `en_GB` by using a file named `messages_en_GB.properties`, in the same location.

Comment: ahh, it has to be in the default classpath. For some reason I've been reading it should be in a resources/messages folder or some variation of that. Thanks!